# Multiply column of PySpark dataframe with scalar

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to multiply a column (say `x3`) of a PySpark dataframe (say `df`) with a scalar (say `0.1`). Below is an example of a dataframe that I have:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "a", 1551.0), (3, "B", 1925.0)], ("x1", "x2", "x3"))

df.show()

+---+---+----+
| x1| x2|  x3|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  a| 5.0|
|  3|  B|21.0|
+---+---+----+
```

Below is what I am trying at present:

```
df_new = df.withColumn( "norm_x3", 0.1*F.col( "x3") )
df_new = df_new.select( [c for c in df_new.columns if c not in {'x3'}] )
```

The method which I am trying above gives the expected output which is:

```
+---+---+-------+
| x1| x2|norm_x3|
+---+---+-------+
|  1|  a|    0.5|
|  3|  B|    2.1|
+---+---+-------+
```

Is there a more elegant and short way of doing the same thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in one line:

```
df.select([(df[c] * 0.1).alias('norm_x3') if c == 'x3' else df[c] for c in df.columns]
```

Or:

```
df.selectExpr('*', 'x3 * 0.1 as normal_x3').drop('x3')
```

Comment: Superb answer, Psidom. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant way would be simply using `drop`:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("norm_x3", 0.1*F.col( "x3")).drop("x3")
```

Alternatively, you can also use `withColumnRenamed`, but is less preferable because you're overloading "x3" and could cause confusion in the future:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("x3", 0.1*F.col( "x3")).withColumnRenamed("x3", "norm_x3")
```

Comment: Wish someone could improve on this to make it more like Pandas.  This is the ugliest code just to do some simple elementary school math.